# web service and application form in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, web-services, asmx

I am using `webservice` and windows application in visual basic i have a code in web service that passes data to web application what i want to do is to display the data to `textbox` in windows application.

this is my code for web service

```
   [WebMethod]
   public string searchCom(string compCode)
   {
        string msg = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALPC\\SQLEXPRESS1; Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectPress", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compCode;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string[] data = new string[3];
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(row["CompanyName"]);
                textBox3.text = Convert.ToDecimal(row["balance"]);
                textBox4.text = Convert.ToDecimal(row["maintBalance"]);
                textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
                textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
                textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
                button1.Visible = false;
                Back.Visible = true;
            }
       }
       return msg;
   }
```

And here is the code on button click inside my windows application(VB)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     string msg = string.Empty; 
     msg = service.searchCom(textBox1.Text); 
}
```

Error is appearing in that `textbox`.

Comment: You mean that you want to consume this web service from your VB windows application. M i right ?

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ yes sir.

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ  yes already done that.

this is my code
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;
            msg = service.searchCom(textBox1.Text);
        }

Comment: actually the error is that the textbox's does not exist in the current context.
what is the alternative solution of that problem?

Comment: the error occurs at textbox2 it say's "textbox2 does not exist in the current context", and so on in other textbox.

Comment: oh God. I didn't see that properly. How can you have textboxes inside your web method. that's wrong. your textboxes should be inside your windows app

Comment: what you can do is... return a datatable from your service . get the first row column values and assign to your controls in ur windows application

Comment: how can i get the return value of service from windows application. Can you show me an example.

Comment: refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/sending-dataset-and-datatable-from-webservice-and-consume-it/   and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5xy331f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: for windows app use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26941/Consuming-Webservice-In-A-Windows-Application